# Tag img doesn’t work in ion-item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I take a picture and I would show the picture in an ion-item inside a list.

photo.ts:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-photo',
  templateUrl: 'photo.html',
})
export class PhotoPage {

  public base64Image: string;

  constructor(
    private camera: Camera
  ) {
  }

  takePicture(){
    this.camera.getPicture({
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      correctOrientation: true

    }).then((imageData) => {

        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

and the photo.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Comment</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Picture</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />

  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button (click)="takePicture()" block>Take a picture</button>

</ion-content>
```

Please note the img tag out of ion-item tag.

In this way, after take a picture, it shows correctly the picture, but if I put the img tag inside ion-item after label Picture, no one picture is showed. To clearify, my template becomes:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Comment</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label fixed>Picture</ion-label>
      <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />   -->  _here the difference_
    </ion-item> 

  </ion-list>

  <button ion-button (click)="takePicture()" block>Take a picture</button>

</ion-content>
```

it doesn’t work and I don’t know why.

NOTE: if I use ion-img tag, it doesn't work like img tag

Comment: how should the label and img look?

Comment: I want to see label followed by the picture

Comment: you could try `ion-thumbnail`.. depends on what size you want to show. ion-item has fixed width and height.. foent depend on content

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/thumbnail/Thumbnail/

Comment: I am not interested to thumbnail, but I want something different. Maybe I can use ion-card, but my question is why in the actual template, it doesn't work. Maybe there is some theoric stuff that I don't know and I would like to know, to avoid issue in the future. Thanks

Comment: you could try fixing height and width of img.. or maybe adding attribute `item-end` to img.. Not sure really.. flying blind here :p

Comment: ehehehe, thank you so much! I will use a ion-card with img inside

Answer (score 1):

```
"<ion-label>
 <ion-img  src=".."></ion-img>
</ion-label>
<ion-input></ion-input>"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and to me it seems that for (V3 at least) that the image has to be inside an ion-label, such as the following:

```
<ion-content padding> 
    <ion-list> 
      <ion-item button *ngFor="let lng of languages" (click)="select(lng.value)" >
        <ion-label text-wrap>
            <img src="{{lng.img}}" >
            {{ lng.text }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark" *ngIf="lng.value == selected"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

**`<ion-img src="..."></ion-img>`**

Comment: I forgot to say, if I use <ion-img [src]="base64Image" ..>, it doesn't work

Comment: ion-img is to be used only with virtual scroll.. check the documentation